# How to specify SQL query in POST method request..?

Tags: javascript, sql, http-post

if I have following controller specifying how to handle SQL queries:

```js
app.controller('sqlController', ['$scope', '$http','$q', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.executeSql = function () {
        $http.post(apiHost + '/sql/query', {sql: $scope.sql,pageNo:$scope.curPageNo}).then(function (res) {
            if(res.data.result==='error'){
                return alert(res.data.errmsg)
            }
            $scope.gridOptions.data = res.data.data;
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = []
            $scope.pageSize = res.data.pageSize;
            $scope.pageNo = res.data.pageNo;
            $scope.count = res.data.count;
            var cols = res.data.data[0];
            var def = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs;
            for(var col in cols){
                def.push({name:col, minWidth: '100'});
            }
        })
    }

    $scope.export = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url:apiHost+"/sql/query",
            method:'POST',
            data:{sql:$scope.sql,pageSize:99999}
        }).success(function(res){
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
        }).error(function(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: [],
        columnDefs: []
    };
}])
```

what should HTTP post request look like?

Something like?:

```html
POST /sql/query HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: some user agent
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,cs;q=0.6
```

The result should be the database name in response.
Thank you for any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to say "Hi", for some reason, every time I add it to original question, it gets automatically removed.

Comment: It depends on your server side. Anyway, it seems weird to expose a service to execute SQL queries. Have you heard about famous attack SQL injection (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) ?

Comment: Thanks, by server side, what exactly do you mean? What file do you expect  to take care of this? (Running nginx/1.8.1, and a lot of Angular libraries are  involved). Yes I am aware of SQLi, this is just test project, so there is nothing to worry about.